# Ubuntu 16.04 Terminal auto-run

Tags: 16.04

I have Ubuntu 16.04 LTS installed on my HP Compaq 6005 SFF and I want to have neofetch run when I open up any terminal application (Yakuake especially)

So how can I make this happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put the command in your .bashrc file in your home directory

```
nano ~/.bashrc
```

Go to the bottom of the file and type neofetch.
Once set there, it will execute every time you start your terminal.
The .bashrc is loaded each time you start a terminal session.

Comment: Where do I find it though when I type it in it gives me this

Comment: No command '~nano' found, did you mean:
 Command 'nano' from package 'nano' (main)
 Command 'rnano' from package 'nano' (main)
~nano: command not found

Comment: (Command from terminal)

Comment: nano is a text editor. Most Linux distributions have it installed by default. It's strange you don't have it. You can use any editor to do this, .bashrc is a simple text file. 

However, you may not be able to see it, because it starts with a dot. Search in your file manager's options and enable showing the hidden files. Then simply open .bashrc with your preferred text editor, go to the bottom and type neofetch.

Comment: Ok thank you for that information and then I add neofetch's command to the .bashrc file right?

Comment: Correct. After that neofetch should be executed each time you open a terminal.

Comment: You could also type `echo neofetch >> ~/.bashrc` into the terminal. That will append the 'neofetch' command to the end of the .bashrc file without the need for opening in a text editor such as nano.

Answer (score 0):

All I did was this

1. nano ~/.bashrc
2. Go down to the bottom and type in this
   a. #NeoFetch (Enter) neofetch
3. Save the file with Control + X, Enter, Y

And thats it! It now works

Answer (score 0):

Open home folder in nautilus,
Show hidden files and open .bashrc to edit it.
Delete Neofetch command at the bottom of the file and click save button.
Open terminal to confirm the script is not running.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question (the poster does want neofetch to run). It also omits important information that would help a user understand what the instructions mean.